# How to upload file in headless mode with button tag

Tags: file-upload, katalon-studio

I'm trying to run file upload in headless mode, I have tried different ways, but not work. How can I get file upload in headless mode?

1. The import button in DOM is like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV96J.png)

It is not input tag, I'm not sure if this will impact on the result ?

2. I need it to run in headless mode.

Following are all the ways I have tried:

1. Using WebUI.uploadFile keyword

Not work in default mode and headless mode.

2. Define custom Keywords like below:

```java
    public class MyTools {

        @Keyword
        def uploadFile (TestObject to, String filePath) {
            WebUI.click(to)
            WebUI.delay(2)
            StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.delay(1000)
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.delay(1000) //NOTE THE DELAY (500, 1000, 1500 MIGHT WORK FOR YOU)
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
    }
```

This way can run in default Chrome mode, but will always fail in headless mode.

3. Use following code:

```java
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

    String path = 'D:\\Daily task\\New PW User.csv'

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/section/div/section[1]/div[1]/div/button")).sendKeys(path);
```

Not work both in default mode and headless mode.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Robot class won't work in headless mode, at least it is [not that simple](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/3FPSc9iEIdY).

Besides, I don't think you need it (it is not clear why would you need it in your example). Try changing the `uploadFile()` method to this:

```
    @Keyword
    def uploadFile (TestObject to, String filePath) {
        WebUI.click(to)
        WebUI.delay(2)
        WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(to, 30)
        element.sendKeys(filePath)
    }
```

**NOTE:**

You will need to import `com.kms.katalon.core.webui.common.WebUiCommonHelper` in order to convert a test object to a web element.